# Arduino client read crlf from http (strip header)

Tags: http, arduino

I'm playing with arduino's wifi shield and trying to strip http header out by searching for CRLF (\r\n) in my loop().

```
   while (client.available()) {
          char c = client.read();
          // I need to check to see if it's crlf 
          // and parse the response.
   }
```

What would be the easiest way to do this? I'm only interested in the response not the header. I thought about putting this in the buffer and look for current and previous character to match crlf (\r\n).

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What did you end up doing? Please share code!

Answer (score -1):

Try using the TextFinder library http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TextFinder

Comment: TextFinder is so slow.

Answer (score -2):

You should probably consider using the existing [HttpClient](https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient/) library or, perhaps, just take a look at how the parsing of HTTP response is implemented there.

Comment: HttpClient requires Ethernet library. He's asked about wifi.